# Basic algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Given an algebraic variety $X$ and 
two $Q$-Cartier divisors $D_1$ and $D_2$.
Given $f \in H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_1))$ and $g\in H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_2))$.

It is always true that $\frac{g}{f}$ is a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D_2-D_1)$
on the open set $D(f)$?

If not, it is a sufficient condition if $D_1$ is Cartier?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem so far :)

Comment: I thought some more. I'm sure that when $D_1$ is Cartier then, $f^{-1} \in H^0(D(f), \mathcal{O}_X(-D_1))$ then it is true. 
Surely, in the $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisors is not true due to this floor function appearing in the definition.